# Django prefetch_related outputs None

Tags: python, django, django-1.11

I'm new to Django. I am making a simple store.
Currently I am working on the Order section. 
Every Order has Order Items inside it. Every order item has some values and a product id.

What I am trying to display on the index.html, is the orders and its items inside it. However `order.items` always outputs `order.OrderItem.None`

views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'order/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_orders'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Order.objects.all().prefetch_related('items')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

views.py

```
# Create your models here.
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='orders')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items')
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    item_price_in_usd = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

index.html

```
{% for order in all_orders %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ order}}</td>
            <td>{{ order.created_at}}</td>
            <td>{{ order.items}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Looking good in first look, have you instead data into the db?

Comment: Yes I can see I have data in the database. order_order and order_orderitem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have found to solution. Apparently you have to add `.all`

```
{% for order in all_orders %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ order}}</td>
            <td>{{ order.created_at}}</td>
            <td>
                {% for items in order.items.all %}
                    <td>{{ items.item_name}}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```